# Check if a variable is undefined in PHP

Tags: php

Consider this JavaScript statement:

```
isTouch = document.createTouch !== undefined
```

I would like to know if we have a similar statement in PHP, not being isset(), but literally checking for an undefined value. Something like:

`$isTouch != ""`

Is there something similar as the above in PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: [Direct link to scorgn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191521/check-if-a-variable-is-undefined-in-php/66253469#66253469) (user names can change at any time).

Comment: I know this is a PHP question but a note about the JS check: if you use `myVar !== undefined` it will throw a `ReferenceError` if the variable doesn't actually exist. Using `typeof myVar !== 'undefined'` doesn't, so it can be used to check variables that may or may not exist.

Answer (score 242, accepted):

You can use -

```
$isTouch = isset($variable);
```

It will return `true` if the `$variable` is defined. If the variable is not defined it will return `false`.

> Note: It returns TRUE if the variable exists and has a value other than NULL, FALSE otherwise.

If you want to check for `false`, `0`, etc., you can then use `empty()` -

```
$isTouch = empty($variable);
```

`empty()` works for -

- **""** *(an empty string)*
- **0** *(0 as an integer)*
- **0.0** *(0 as a float)*
- **"0"** *(0 as a string)*
- **NULL**
- **FALSE**
- **array()** *(an empty array)*
- **$var;** *(a variable declared, but without a value)*

Comment: `isset()` always returns bool.

Comment: Is the boolean cast necessary ? isset(...) does already return bool right ?

Comment: No. It return `true` or `false`. So no need of that casting.

Comment: you could also do this by using the `empty()` which would return false if it is an empty string. `isset()` will return true if its an empty string, also empty does a isset check internally.

Comment: you could also do this: `$isTouch = (bool) $variable;` which will do the same as `isset()` and is maybe a little better since it will work like `empty()`.

Comment: @mic - IMHO its better to use `isset` or `!empty`, as those don't generate a php warning (in your web log) for an unset variable. `E_NOTICE Undefined variable $variable`.  I think you can suppress those warnings, but personally I prefer to not generate them in the first place.

Comment: I would argue that !isset(...) does NOT check whether a value is undefined. It checks if it is either undefined or null. I think it's important to note that things can be defined as null.

Comment: @scorgn answer explains why this solution may not be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 35):

### The `isset()` function does not check if a variable is defined.

It seems you've specifically stated that you're not looking for `isset()` in the question. I don't know why there are so many answers stating that `isset()` is the way to go, or why the accepted answer states that as well.

It's important to realize in programming that null is something. I don't know why it was decided that `isset()` would return false if the value is null.

To check if a variable is undefined you will have to check if the variable is in the list of defined variables, using `get_defined_vars()`. There is no equivalent to JavaScript's undefined (which is what was shown in the question, no jQuery being used there).

In the following example it will work the same way as JavaScript's undefined check.

```php
$isset = isset($variable);
var_dump($isset); // false
```

But in this example, it won't work like JavaScript's undefined check.

```php
$variable = null;
$isset = isset($variable);
var_dump($isset); // false
```

`$variable` is being defined as null, but the `isset()` call still fails.

### So how do you actually check if a variable is defined? You check the defined variables.

Using `get_defined_vars()` will return an associative array with keys as variable names and values as the variable values. We still can't use `isset(get_defined_vars()['variable'])` here because the key could exist and the value still be null, so we have to use `array_key_exists('variable', get_defined_vars())`.

```
$variable = null;
$isset = array_key_exists('variable', get_defined_vars());
var_dump($isset); // true


$isset = array_key_exists('otherVariable', get_defined_vars());
var_dump($isset); // false
```

However, if you're finding that in your code you have to check for whether a variable has been defined or not, then you're likely doing something wrong. This is my personal belief as to why the core PHP developers left `isset()` to return false when something is null.

Comment: This, is the right answer! As for checking if a variable is defined, it's sometimes useful when working on a shi\*y code with global vars all over the place. And why did the PHP folks decide to have *isset()* return *false* if the variable *is* defined and contains *null*... that's another mystery on Earth!

Comment: Thanks, this marks the end of my boggling at `isset()`'s curious blind-spot for `null`.

As for the "doing something wrong" rationale, after brief consideration I can't point to a non-sketchy scenario for needing to know if a `null` variable exists, but for an array member there are most certainly cases of a meaningful `null`, e.g. when using prepared statements with `PDO`.

Comment: This is only right answer on this page.  Learned the hard way.

Comment: Nice explanation. `isset` may be working like so for compatibility reasons (it exists since php 4).

Answer (score 25):

Another way is simply:

```
if($test){
    echo "Yes 1";
}
if(!is_null($test)){
    echo "Yes 2";
}

$test = "hello";

if($test){
    echo "Yes 3";
}
```

Will return:

```
"Yes 3"
```

The best way is to use isset(). Otherwise you can have an error like "undefined $test".

You can do it like this:

```
if(isset($test) && ($test!==null))
```

You'll not have any error, because the first condition isn't accepted.

Comment: If we use `$test!==null` without brackets, then what will happened? Will it give error?

Comment: No, it's ok too.

Comment: Case 1 and 2 will throw a warning. This is not a proper way to check if the value is undefined.

Comment: `isset() would return false if the value is null`

Comment: "The best way is to use isset(). Otherwise you can have an error like "undefined $test"." 
OP is asking exactly how to check when a variable is undefined! Or when a piece of code will return the warning that you mentioned: probably he wants to intercept such case!

Answer (score 10):

To check if a variable is set you need to use the [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function.

```
$lorem = 'potato';

if(isset($lorem)){
    echo 'isset true' . '<br />';
}else{
    echo 'isset false' . '<br />';
}

if(isset($ipsum)){
    echo 'isset true' . '<br />';
}else{
    echo 'isset false' . '<br />';
}
```

This code will print:

```
isset true
isset false
```

Read more in *[isset](https://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)*.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) to check whether the value is set by POST/GET or not. Something like this:

```
$value1 = $_POST['value1'] = isset($_POST['value1']) ? $_POST['value1'] : '';
$value2 = $_POST['value2'] = isset($_POST['value2']) ? $_POST['value2'] : '';
$value3 = $_POST['value3'] = isset($_POST['value3']) ? $_POST['value3'] : '';
$value4 = $_POST['value4'] = isset($_POST['value4']) ? $_POST['value4'] : '';
```

Comment: PHP 7.0 introduced the [Null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce) which is designed for things like this. The code is then `$value1 = $_POST["value1"] ?? "fallback"`.

Comment: Nice catch @miile7!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the PHP **isset()** function to test whether a variable is set or not. The **isset()** will return FALSE if testing a variable that has been set to NULL. Example:

```
<?php
    $var1 = '';
    if(isset($var1)){
        echo 'This line is printed, because the $var1 is set.';
    }
?>
```

This code will output "This line is printed, because the $var1 is set."

read more in https://stackhowto.com/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-undefined-in-php/

Comment: But null is a value after all, and $var1 = null is something I could use in an if. So no cigar.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript's 'strict not equal' operator (`!==`) on comparison with `undefined` does **not** result in `false` on `null` values.

```
var createTouch = null;
isTouch = createTouch !== undefined  // true
```

To achieve an equivalent behaviour in PHP, you can check whether the variable name exists in the keys of the result of `get_defined_vars()`.

```
// just to simplify output format
const BR = '<br>' . PHP_EOL;

// set a global variable to test independence in local scope
$test = 1;

// test in local scope (what is working in global scope as well)
function test()
{
  // is global variable found?
  echo '$test ' . ( array_key_exists('test', get_defined_vars())
                    ? 'exists.' : 'does not exist.' ) . BR;
  // $test does not exist.

  // is local variable found?
  $test = null;
  echo '$test ' . ( array_key_exists('test', get_defined_vars())
                    ? 'exists.' : 'does not exist.' ) . BR;
  // $test exists.

  // try same non-null variable value as globally defined as well
  $test = 1;
  echo '$test ' . ( array_key_exists('test', get_defined_vars())
                    ? 'exists.' : 'does not exist.' ) . BR;
  // $test exists.

  // repeat test after variable is unset
  unset($test);
  echo '$test ' . ( array_key_exists('test', get_defined_vars())
                    ? 'exists.' : 'does not exist.') . BR;
  // $test does not exist.
}

test();
```

In most cases, `isset($variable)` is appropriate. That is aquivalent to `array_key_exists('variable', get_defined_vars()) && null !== $variable`. If you just use `null !== $variable` without prechecking for existence, you will mess up your logs with warnings because that is an attempt to read the **value** of an undefined variable.

However, you can apply an undefined variable to a reference without any warning:

```
// write our own isset() function
function my_isset(&$var)
{
  // here $var is defined
  // and initialized to null if the given argument was not defined
  return null !== $var;
}

// passing an undefined variable by reference does not log any warning
$is_set = my_isset($undefined_variable);   // $is_set is false
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the `my_isset` function would accomplish. The only thing it will determine is if a variable is set to null without throwing an error, not if the variable is defined. `$string = 'string'; $is_set = my_isset($string);`In this case `$is_set` would be false, even though it is set to a string.

Comment: @scorgn There was a typo. After saying 'If you just use null !== $variable' of course it should not be `===` in the following function. Just edited.

Answer (score 3):

The **easiest way** to check if a `variable` or `array index` exists (is defined) and *is not null* and *is not empty* and *is not false*:

**#1**

```
if($variable ?? false) 
    echo '$variable is defined';
else 
    echo '$variable is not defined';

// Result: $variable is not defined
```

**#2**

```
$variable = null;

if($variable ?? false) 
    echo '$variable is not null';
else 
    echo '$variable is null';

// Result: $variable is null
```

**#3**

```
$variable = false;

if($variable ?? false) 
    echo '$variable is not false';
else 
    echo '$variable is false';

// Result: $variable is false
```

**#4**

```
$variable = '';

if($variable ?? false) 
    echo '$variable is not empty';
else 
    echo '$variable is empty';

// Result: $variable is empty
```

Comment: I'd say this solution is the easiest, and probably fine in most cases. It may not be suitable for situations where you need to distinguish between undefined / null / false / true values.