# check if a variable is defined (null or not)

Tags: php

I would like to test if a variable exists
This variable can be set to null.

Is there a function can test that?

`isset()` returns false if the variable exists but defined to null.
I can't use `is_null()` if my `$var` is not defined.

Edit:
my var is an object property so I did this:

`property_exists($pData, $key)`

and that works

Thx

Comment: Nope! There is no built-in function aimed for that specific requirement.

Comment: There is no built-in function to check is variable exists in PHP.
[`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)  is proper way to check is variable is set or exists.
There is also [`defined()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) function which work only for contasts.
See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191521/php-check-if-variable-is-undefined)

Comment: `isset(get_defined_vars()['var'])` will work in global scope or in method function scope.

Comment: my var is an object property so I did this: `property_exists($pData, $key)` and it works

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can - and you probably shouldn't. However, if you aren't using methods you can check the global scope:

```
$x = null;

var_dump(array_key_exists('x', $GLOBALS)); # true
var_dump(array_key_exists('y', $GLOBALS)); # false
```

See also https://3v4l.org/Sl8Wi