# Php: check if variable value exist as a variable || make variable value a variable

Tags: php, if-statement, variables, variable-names

Is it possible to check if a variable exist using a variable value?
Like

```
//some variables:
$variable_a;
$variable_b;
$variable_c;
$variable_d;

$variable = '$variable_b';
     if (the content $variable which is '$variable_b' exists == true){
    
}
```

or how to make a variable value into a variable?
Like

$variable = 'variable_name';
...some code to make 'variable_name' a variable

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Not sure I understand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a variable is undefined in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191521/check-if-a-variable-is-undefined-in-php)

Comment: More specifically, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66253469/4964822) there. We also expect you to do some Google search before asking.

Comment: @nice_dev I'm not talking about isset() because I think it checks the variable itself instead of the variable value. Not really sure though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) in PHP, and then check if such a variable has a value. For instance:

```
$variableA = 'Hello';
$variableB = 'variableA';
echo ${$variableB};
```

returns `Hello` on your screen. You can also check if `$variableA` has a value by doing:

```
if (isset(${$variableB})) {
    ....
}
```

Note that in your question you have variables that have no value, they are not set. The whole purpose of variables is to have a value, hence their name, so your variables are some kind of zombies, not really alive, not really dead. They are not set, so `isset()` will return `false`.